# How to create DTO object with collections

Tags: java, spring, dto

I am writing application using Spring framework. I want to create dto model for my entity object and using it in spring controller. It is not difficult, but I have a relation between my table in database and I must have set in my entity object.

User entity

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "personalId")
    private String personalId;
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoleSet;
```

user_roles entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    private User user;
```

Table user have a relation one to many to user_role table.
I create a DTO object for this entities:

userDto

```
public class UserDto {

    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String username;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String password;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String lastName;
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
    private String personalId;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String city;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String address;
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String email;
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    private String phone;
    private Set<UserRoleDto> userRoleSetDto;
```

userRoleDto

```
public class UserRoleDto {

    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String name;
    private UserDto userDto;
```

My controller which redirects to a page with a list of users

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/adminlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView goAdminList() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("admin/adminlist");
    List<UserDto> admins = prepareUserListDto(userService.getAdminList());
    mav.addObject("admins", admins);
    return mav;
}
```

In this controller I prepare user list to userdto list, using method prepareUserListDto:

```
private List<UserDto> prepareUserListDto(List<User> users) {
    List<UserDto> userDtoList = null;
    if (users != null && !users.isEmpty()) {
        userDtoList = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
        UserDto userDto = null;
        for (User user : users) {
            userDto = new UserDto();
            userDto.setId(user.getId());
            userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
            userDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
            userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            userDto.setUserRoleSetDto(prepareUserRoleDtoSet(user
                    .getUserRoleSet()));
            userDtoList.add(userDto);
        }
    }
    return userDtoList;
}
```

this method invoke to method to prepare userRole to userRoleDto

```
private Set<UserRoleDto> prepareUserRoleDtoSet(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    Set<UserRoleDto> userRoleDtoSet = null;
    if (userRoles != null && !userRoles.isEmpty()) {
        userRoleDtoSet = new HashSet<UserRoleDto>();
        UserRoleDto userRoleDto = null;
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            userRoleDto = new UserRoleDto();
            userRoleDto.setId(userRole.getId());
            userRoleDto.setName(userRole.getName());
            userRoleDto.setUserDto(prepareUserDto(userRole.getUser()));
            userRoleDtoSet.add(userRoleDto);
        }
    }
    return userRoleDtoSet;
}
```

but this method again invoke to method:

```
private UserDto prepareUserDto(User user) {
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.setId(user.getId());
    userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    userDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    userDto.setUserRoleSetDto(prepareUserRoleDtoSet(user.getUserRoleSet()));
    return userDto;
}
```

In conclusion when i try show the admin list I have recursive call and i get this error:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:166)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserRoleDtoSet(AdminController.java:170)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserDto(AdminController.java:139)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserRoleDtoSet(AdminController.java:177)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserDto(AdminController.java:139)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserRoleDtoSet(AdminController.java:177)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserDto(AdminController.java:139)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserRoleDtoSet(AdminController.java:177)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserDto(AdminController.java:139)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserRoleDtoSet(AdminController.java:177)
>       pl.piotr.ibank.controller.AdminController.prepareUserDto(AdminController.java:139)

Line 139 is `userDto.setUserRoleSetDto(prepareUserRoleDtoSet(user.getUserRoleSet()));` in `private UserDto prepareUserDto(User user)` method and Line 177 is `private UserDto prepareUserDto(User user)` in `private Set<UserRoleDto> prepareUserRoleDtoSet(Set<UserRole> userRoles)` method.

How to write dto for this entity? If it would not have a constraint this is easy, but my entity have a constraint between user and user_role and I don't know how to good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to remove completely the `userDto` property from the UserRoleDto class. In contrast to the entity classes where you might need to go from one entity to another and include bi-directional relations, the client will usually only need to get the roles of a user, and never users from a role. Therefore you do not need bi-directional relations between those two dtos

Answer (score 3):

You have a bi-directionnal relation between UserDto and UserRoleDto.

If you really need to keep the bi-directional relation, I would modify your code as follow :

```
private UserDto prepareUserDto(User user) {
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.setId(user.getId());
    userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    userDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
    userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    userDto.setUserRoleSetDto(prepareUserRoleDtoSet(user.getUserRoleSet(), userDto));
    return userDto;
}
```

This pass the userDto being created to prepareUserRoleDtoSet.

```
private Set<UserRoleDto> prepareUserRoleDtoSet(Set<UserRole> userRoles, UserDto userDto) {
    Set<UserRoleDto> userRoleDtoSet = null;
    if (userRoles != null && !userRoles.isEmpty()) {
        userRoleDtoSet = new HashSet<UserRoleDto>();
        UserRoleDto userRoleDto = null;
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            userRoleDto = new UserRoleDto();
            userRoleDto.setId(userRole.getId());
            userRoleDto.setName(userRole.getName());
            userRoleDto.setUserDto(userDto);
            userRoleDtoSet.add(userRoleDto);
        }
    }
    return userRoleDtoSet;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare the attribute `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` on the collection of roles. So when hibernate gives you a `User` the collection of its `UserRole` is already initialized. And even if it was not, it would be initialized on first call to `getUserRoleSet()`. You can simply write :

```
private List<UserDto> prepareUserListDto(List<User> users) {
    List<UserDto> userDtoList = null;
    Set<UserRoleDto> roleDtoSet = null;
    if (users != null && !users.isEmpty()) {
        userDtoList = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
        UserDto userDto = null;
        for (User user : users) {
            userDto = new UserDto();
            userDto.setId(user.getId());
            userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
            userDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
            userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            roleDtoSet = new HashSet<UserRoleDto>();
            for (UserRole role: user.getUserRoleSet) {
                UserRoleDto roleDto = new UserRoleDto();
                roleDto.setId(role.getId());
                roleDto.setUserDto(userDto);
                roleDto.setName(user.getName);
                roleDtoSet.add(roleDto);
            }
            userDto.setUserRoleSetDto(roleDtoSet);
            userDtoList.add(userDto);
        }
    }
    return userDtoList;
}
```

If you prefere small methods (easier to write and test), you can split it, almost the same you wrote but passing `userDto` that you already have :

```
private List<UserDto> prepareUserListDto(List<User> users) {
    List<UserDto> userDtoList = null;
    if (users != null && !users.isEmpty()) {
        userDtoList = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
        UserDto userDto = null;
        for (User user : users) {
            userDto = new UserDto();
            userDto.setId(user.getId());
            userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            userDto.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
            userDto.setLastName(user.getLastName());
            userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            userDto.setUserRoleSetDto(prepareUserRoleDtoSet(userDto, user
                    .getUserRoleSet()));
            userDtoList.add(userDto);
        }
    }
    return userDtoList;
}

private Set<UserRoleDto> prepareUserRoleDtoSet(UserDto userDto,
        Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    Set<UserRoleDto> userRoleDtoSet = null;
    if (userRoles != null && !userRoles.isEmpty()) {
        userRoleDtoSet = new HashSet<UserRoleDto>();
        UserRoleDto userRoleDto = null;
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            userRoleDto = new UserRoleDto();
            userRoleDto.setId(userRole.getId());
            userRoleDto.setName(userRole.getName());
            userRoleDto.setUserDto(userDto);
            userRoleDtoSet.add(userRoleDto);
        }
    }
    return userRoleDtoSet;
}
```

This avoids all cyclic dependancy.